# sqlsrv_connect() keep connection in application pool active

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have a php script that connects to a local SQL server database through sqlsrv_connect.

```
  $serverName = "127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER";
  $userName = 'username';
  $userPassword = 'pass';
  $dbName = "name";
  $connectionInfo = array("database"=>$dbName,
                              "UID"=>$userName,
                              "PWD"=>$userPassword, 
                              "MultipleActiveResultSets"=>true,
                              "ConnectionPooling"=>true);

  sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 0);

  $this->connection = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

The first time that i load the website this code under is executing in about 1.5sec

```
$this->connection = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

If i reload the page the execution time for the same line is 0.0012 - 0.0020sec (much faster)

If i wait for lets say for 10 minutes and try to reload the page again the execution time for connect is over 1sec

Is there anything i can do to keep the connection "active" so to make the `sqlsrv_connect` runs faster?

1. IIS Application pool idle shutdown is disable
2. MSSQL Server connection timeout is 0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3):

Why are you using sqlsrv_connect()?

look at mysqli much newer and still being developet.(my english)

[Mysqli PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)